# DataExplorer Feature request: Associate OpenID with other accounts in the trilogy, then allow push-button insertion of the user's own UserID

Tags: bug, data-explorer, linked-accounts, status-completed

With the new site, there is (understandably, since it's barely even been announced) no tie-in with accounts on the other sites.

If/when account association gets added, it would be nice to add the ability to click a button and have the "UserId" parameter that a lot of the scripts require populate with your UserId for the site in question.

It should be optional, because some people are likely to look at other users' data for whatever reason.

Comment: Looking at the FAQ (http://odata.stackexchange.com/faq), it looks like this is in the pipeline: "We will automatically populate any parameter named ##UserId## with your user id on the respective sites (if your EmailHash matches)"

Comment: sorry peoples, this is a regression that I just fixed in dev

Comment: Ok I fixed the functionality, Im retagging this a bug with status-completed

Comment: @waffles - I get the default number of 1838, which [isn't me](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1838).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it is not clear if you realise this feature *is* already present (although it *is* currently based on matching EmailHash).

It changed slightly about when waffles implemented the read-only concept but now if you are logged in to odata and go to my [all comments query](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/75/my-comments); click `Run Query` and your UserId will be automatically populated in the field. Click `Run Query` again to actually execute the query.

EDIT: Just confirming the behaviour has returned to automatically inserting your UserId, if you're logged in.

Comment: Poster Margaret and commenter Margaret are the same person. Check the urls on the name. Also the question poster's name is highlighted on comments - unlike mine on this one.

Comment: Ah.  The fact that "Run query" did it was unclear.  I have a feeling that may want to rearrange the UI around that point somehow, because I just worked on the assumption that if I tried to submit without the parameters filled, it would send me to a "Please fill out the parameters" page.

Comment: @ChrisF I've removed the parenthetic phrase. I wrote the answer not needing to know who posted the question, but the commenter needed identifying. I didn't think to check if they were the same person!

Comment: @Margaret The now changed behaviour was that the UserId was placed in the field immediately. I guess it was changed once waffles implemented the fields being specified in the GET URL request.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like it to be optional just for the ability to query other people. Maybe there could be a better ##EmailHash## or something that would tie in.

This is a shameless plug but I found looking for my UserId to be annoying as hell, so I posted this query as a base: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/136/use-displayname-not-userid-please.

You can do joins on the Users table pretty easily but for some reason my mind wasn't operating in SQL mode to try to edit some of the existing queries. DisplayName isn't the best idea (use Marko to see why) but plugging in my name or Jeff Atwood shows the correct result.